# JQuery embed in php echo. dont success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i want to use Jquery ajax

```
echo "$(document).ready(function() {
          $(\"#submit\").click(function(){
                var n = $(\"#n\").val();  

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: \"GET\",
                    url: \"function.php\",
                    data: \"n=\"+n,
                    success: function(results)
                    {
                        alert(n);                       

                    }
               });
          });
      });";
```

but never it shows the alert(n);

Can you help me?

---

Edit:
I try to do it with only js but dont work too.. here is it.

```
<script>
  var n = $('#n').val(); 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      var n = $("#n").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: "n=" + n,
        url: 'function.php',
        success: function (results) {
            alert(results);
            alert("some");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form action='' method='post'>
  <select name='n'  id='n'>
    <option value='Lusiana'>Lusiana</option>
  </select>
  <input id='submit' name='submit' type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

I'm using this code: 
https://github.com/papalevski/jQuerySlider/tree/master/jQuerySlider

the php is:

```
<?php
  $n = ( isset($_GET['n']) ? $_GET['n'] : "");
  echo $n;
?>
```

Comment: any error in console and what is / in your code ??

Comment: have you intentionally used `\"` in place of `"` everywhere or is it just accidental. In case it is not intended please edit the code to reflect the same.

Comment: @LakshayGarg  He said this code is inside of a PHP echo statement.

Comment: Your "alert(n)" is shown inside of the success method, which means the alert will only appear when the ajax GET is successful. Change the alert inside of the success function to alert(results) and the alert(n) before the ajax request.

Comment: alert(n); before ajax request shows Lusiana but nothing success with alert(results)  .

Comment: This means that your ajax request isn't being successful, then. Make sure that your php script exists correctly, and does not contain errors.

Comment: I've updated your PHP. Your PHP error may lie in the fact that you did not have brackets in your else statement. I avoid inline statements that use "if" and "else". The "$n =" is set by a inline if statement though.

Comment: i like your update but error still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) your code, it will be less difficult to read, data should be sent like `data: {n:"value"}`, in your case i think this must work `data:{n:\""+n+"\"},`

```
echo "$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#submit').click(function(){
              var n = $('#n').val();  
              jQuery.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'function.php',
                  data: {n:n},
                  success: function(results){                      
                      alert(n)
                  }
              });
          });
      });";
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant n- assumed 'n' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\index.php on line 167. and dont have solve this :/

Comment: sorry but is the same thing, idk why i havent response

Comment: maybe it's `$('#n').val();`, what is `$('#n')`? you could try just to user a random string to test ajax like `var n='123';`

Comment: Why would you escape the first quote but not the second? The second quote would end the PHP echo and would would use \"" . $n . "\" which would output "{n}" in js. The n variable is for js, so it would correctly be \" + n + \"

Comment: well i finally solve this with new scenario. thanks all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Place your script code inside Nowdocs block, It will be more easier for you to read and/or debug,

The benefit is, you don't have to escape those characters as double quotes and/or single quotes.

Read about it more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
$now = <<<'SCRIPT'

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var n = $("#n").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "function.php",
            data: "n=" + n,
            success: function(results) {
                alert(n);

            }
        });
    });
});

SCRIPT;
```

Comment: ok i make it and change the data for data: {"n":n} but doesnt work too.